# Name is null from apple sign in. its a new user, firebase react native

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-sign-in

Hi I cannot get the user's name via APPLE SSO.
Im using react native firebase. It logs in fine.

I made sure its a new account for the app.

- in firebase console > auth > removed my apple user email.
- https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage > sign in with security > sign in with Apple > and "Stop using sign in with apple" on that app. the private relay email matches in firebase and is removed.

how do i get the name from apple SSO?

```
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import { appleAuth } from '@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication';

async function onAppleButtonPress() {
  const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
    requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
    requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL, appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME],
  });

  if (!appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken) {
    throw new Error('Apple Sign-In failed - no identify token returned');
  }

  const { identityToken, nonce } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
  const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(identityToken, nonce);

  const res = await auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential);

  console.log('res', res) //  <-- see next code block

  // below, displayname is null, i do see firebase Id, and the private email relay address.
  console.log('auth().currentUser?', auth().currentUser )

  return res
}
```

```
// res response
{
  "additionalUserInfo": {
    "profile": {
      "is_private_email": "true",
      "sub": "000630.afe8c07332204888...",
      "exp": 1666292000,
      "real_user_status": 2,
      "iss": "https://appleid.apple.com",
      "c_hash": "yXmD5j_37t1F...",
      "email_verified": "true",
      "aud": "com.mydemo.app",
      "iat": 1666205600,\
      "email": "kgszm...@privaterelay.appleid.com",        
      "auth_time": 1666205600,        
      "nonce": "77e6cd4bfca826abc77a179f15b0a8...",        
      "nonce_supported": true      
    },      
    "username": null,      
    "providerId": "apple.com",      
    "isNewUser": true             <---- shows its a new user
  },    
  "user": {      
    "isAnonymous": false,      
    "emailVerified": true,      
    "providerData": [        
      {          
        "providerId": "apple.com",          
        "uid": "000630.afe8c0733220488889977a5c9...",          
        "email": "kgszm...@privaterelay.appleid.com",          
      }      ],      
      "uid": "4VpWSNUxVAeNzuEu4IQrLKq5Mw43",      
      "email": "kgszm...@privaterelay.appleid.com",          
      "refreshToken": "AOEOulaKPm6HzbT....",      
      "displayName": null,             <--- why is this null?
      "tenantId": null,      
      "phoneNumber": null,      
      "photoURL": null,      
      "metadata": {        
      "creationTime": 1666205601897,        
      "lastSignInTime": 1666205601897      
    },      
    "providerId": "firebase"    
    }  
  }}'
```

"@react-native-firebase/auth@^12.9.0": version "12.9.3"

Comment: Having the same issue with 
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^15.3.0",
"@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

AS described in invertase readme file, apple API provide fullName only the first time, you need to save it in signup the first time.

For testing purpose you can delete using apple account form settings/security and password/delete apple account of your application.

```
const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
  requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
  requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME, appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL],
});
// Create a Firebase credential from the response
const { identityToken, nonce, fullName } = appleAuthRequestResponse;
const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(identityToken, nonce);
let fullName_ = '';
if(fullName.namePrefix) fullName_ = fullName_ + fullName.namePrefix + ' ';
if(fullName.givenName) fullName_ = fullName_ + fullName.givenName + ' ';
if(fullName.familyName) fullName_ = fullName_ + fullName.familyName + ' ';
if(fullName.nickname) fullName_ = fullName_ + fullName.nickname + ' ';
if(fullName.middleName) fullName_ = fullName_ + fullName.middleName + ' ';
if(fullName.nameSuffix) fullName_ = fullName_ + fullName.nameSuffix + ' ';
```